# htaccess regular expressions don't allow "dot"

Tags: .htaccess

Here's the code I tried in the **.htaccess** file. **it allows 0-9 a-z A-Z underscore and hyphen**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# User page
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) testtwo.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

But once I changed the last line of code as follows **to accept "dot/period"** it doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9a-zA-Z_-.]+) testtwo.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

**or**

```
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9a-zA-Z_-\.]+) testtwo.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

Your advice highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Have a try placing the . _before_ the hyphen.. Why? Think of the special meaning of the hyphen...

Comment: @arkascha thank you for the reply. `RewriteRule ^test/([0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+) testtwo.php?u=$1 [NC,L]` and `RewriteRule ^test/([0-9a-zA-Z_\.-]+) testtwo.php?u=$1 [NC,L]` **Still not working**

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ? What error do you get with the rule you have tried?

Comment: Please add a definite test case to your question. So a URL you request, so that we can try that.

Answer (score 0):

Check this modified regex

```
RewriteRule ^test\/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-\.]+)$ testtwo.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```